# How to use Vue Router after App.vue Axios request finish?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router, pinia, casl

So, I have my project, that I'm using Pinia + Casl, and everything works perfectly except when I try to reload my page.

Of course, I have an entire structure that creates all over the Casl permissions again (I don't let anything be stored).

The problem is that Casl is checking the permission to access the current page (using beforeEach) before my Axios request has finished, so I can set the permissions to Casl, which makes it deny access.

I have this on my App.vue (that I understand it's the right place to call what you need on page reload):

```
const authStore = useAuthStore()

// This is a functions calling an Axios request
  authStore.setBasicAbilities()
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      authStore.logout()
    })
```

In my Main.js I have the Plugins set like this:

```
app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability, {
  useGlobalProperties: true,
})
piniaPlugin.use(({ store }) => {
  store.$router = markRaw(router)
})
app.use(piniaPlugin)
app.use(router)
app.use(layoutsPlugin)
app.use(i18n)
```

In my Router I have this:

```
router.beforeEach(to => {
  const userStore = useUserStore(store)
  const isLoggedIn = userStore.isUserLoggedIn()
  if (canNavigate(to)) {
    if (to.meta.redirectIfLoggedIn && isLoggedIn)
      return '/'
  }
  else {
    if (isLoggedIn)
      return { name: 'not-authorized' }
    else
      return { name: 'login', query: { to: to.name !== 'index' ? to.fullPath : undefined } }
  }
})
```

Now, my question is: what should I do, for router usage wait for my Axios request to be finish ?

Comment: Try setting the `authStore.setBasicAbilities()`request into the `beforeEnter` function in the route itself? I guess it's the index `/` for you which is assigned to your App.vue. Sorry I'm not familiar with Casl so might have to do something else too with it. Just my first thought.

Comment: Make beforeEach async and use `await authStore.setBasicAbilities()`

Comment: I solved it, doing data validation, to check if the user is logged in, how is the permissions level and to know if it has already created Casl abilities. I do all this inside beforeEach anyway.